# Disqus `count.js` displays '0 Comments' on production

Tags: comments, ruby-on-rails-3.2, disqus

The comment count on my `index` page doesn't reflect the actual count for each `entry` in my blog.  When running locally in `development` it reflects the actual count, but once I push it to `production` on [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) it displays '0 Comments and 0 Reactions', even though there is at least one comment.  I added the JS that Disqus provides at the bottom of my `index.html.haml` and added a link for the comment count.  Here's my code for scrutinizing:

```
%p
  = "* Comments - "
  = link_to e, entry_path(e, :anchor => "disqus_thread")
.date= e.updated_at.strftime('* %a, %b %-e, %Y @ %l:%M %p %Z') 
%br

:javascript
  /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
  var disqus_shortname = 'heneman'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

  /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
  (function () {
    var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
    (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
  }());
```

Also, [here](http://kyleheneman.info) is a link to my blog.  If you look at the second entry down (titled "Add Markdown To A Rails 3.2 App") you'll see the comment count displays '0', but if you click on the title and go into the `show` page for that entry, you'll see there's a comment.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the `disqus-identifier` as `data-disqus-identifier` in your comment link as described [here](http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624-tightening-your-disqus-integration). Look at your front page HTML source code for start page. Its rendering `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>` for every post out there which is not a standard i think.

Comment: Where do you see the `DOCTYPE` declarations repeated for every `entry`?  It only appears once at the top of the document like it's supposed to.  I'll let you know how things go with the `data-disqus-identifier`, but honestly I don't think that's the issue.  I don't have `data-disqus-identifier` on it currently and the comment count shows up correctly when I'm running it locally.  It's only once it's pushed to Heroku that it displays '0 comments'

Comment: Ahhh, I was looking at it with Firebug.  Thanks, I'll look into it later today when I get a chance

Comment: So!  I write each `entry` in Markdown and have Redcarpet configured for XHTML output.  ~That's where all of the `DOCTYPE` declarations are coming from!~  Thanks for pointing this out @dlnGd0ng.  Er, rather, it's coming from the Markdown renderer, not the XHTML configuration.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, the `DOCTYPE`s were there on my local environment also and the comment count is working fine, so it's not the multiple `DOCTYPE` declarations but I did remove them.

Comment: did u tried the data-disqus-identifier? Does ur test and production blog entries contain the same disqus-identifier? In that case you should specify the data-disqus-identifier attribute on the links

Comment: Yeah, I knew how to add them, I just never did because it was working locally \*face palm\*. After adding them they links are displaying the correct comment counts!  Thanks much!